# What is $[\mathbb{Q}(a) : \mathbb{Q}(a+1/a) ]$?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

I've been thinking about this for a while and I keep confusing myself, so hopefully someone can help clarify some thoughts.

I'm currently looking at two fields, $\mathbb{Q}(a+1/a)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(a)$, where $a$ is just some algebraic number (in some of the examples I'm looking at, it isn't a number that can be expressed by radicals, which I imagine makes a difference in some cases).

I believe we have that $\mathbb{Q}(a+1/a) \subset \mathbb{Q}(a)$, so we have a field extension $\mathbb{Q}(a) / \mathbb{Q}(a+1/a)$. But what can we say about the degree of this extension?

(In saying this, I'm unsure if this is actually true: every element of $\mathbb{Q}(a+1/a)$ is of the form $u + v(a+1/a) \in \mathbb{Q}(a)$...that is enough to conclude that $\mathbb{Q}(a+1/a) \subset \mathbb{Q}(a)$ in this case, yes?)

I know that in some cases, it's trivial. For example, if $a = \sqrt{2}$, then $\mathbb{Q}(a+1/a) =\mathbb{Q}(a)$. But as I say, in some cases I look at, $a$ cannot be expressed by radicals.

So far, the only real thought I've had is to use Tower Law, with the tower: $\mathbb{Q}(a) / \mathbb{Q}(a+1/a) / \mathbb{Q}$.
This gives $[\mathbb{Q}(a) : \mathbb{Q}(a+1/a)] < [\mathbb{Q}(a) : \mathbb{Q}]$.
**But can anything stronger be said?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that:
$$a^2 - \left(a+\frac1a\right) a + 1 = 0$$
i.e. $a$ satisfies a quadratic with coefficients in $\Bbb Q\!\left(a+1/a\right)$, so $\Bbb Q(a)/\Bbb Q(a+1/a)$ is at most quadratic, so $[\Bbb Q(a):\Bbb Q(a+1/a)] \le 2$.

---

It is $1$ iff the equation already has a root in $\Bbb Q(a+1/a)$, which happens iff the discriminant $\left(a+\dfrac1a\right)^2 - 4 = \left(a-\dfrac1a\right)^2$ is a square in $\Bbb Q(a+1/a)$, which occurs iff $a-\dfrac1a \in \Bbb Q(a+1/a)$.

But this criterion is useless because $a-\dfrac1a \in \Bbb Q(a+1/a)$ iff $\dfrac1{2a} \in \Bbb Q(a+1/a)$ iff $a \in \Bbb Q(a+1/a)$.